# How to find common values in excel using vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to find out the common values in excel, I have four different columns in excel . ColumnB , ColumnG , ColumnM and ColumnQ , I am applying vlookup to extract the common values in these four columns

```
=VLOOKUP(B4,$B$4:$Q$33,1,FALSE)
```

**I have total of 33 rows in all the four columns , by applying the vlookup i am not getting the correct answer, Any help would be appreciated.**

Sample Data

[image]

Required output will be A

Comment: @BigBen i give me a min

Comment: @BigBen I have Edited the question

Comment: Where would the output be? Need to see how you want this outputed to know type of formula so please add a photo showing the desired output GIVEN the sample data you provided. Will you have a table of all unique values and then output a boolean response? If so, you can just use COUNTIF = 4 (one for each column).

Comment: @urdearboy I want to show all the common values in some column that might be column X or Column Y or Column Z.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INDEX/MATCH/COUNTIF combination to do this but it's going to be painfully slow if left looking at the entire column.

You can speed it up a little by adjusting the formula to not look into the entire column - instead, only look in the used range. If you convert your range into a table you can modify the formula to look at table columns which means you won't have to continuously update the ranges used in formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E$1:E1, A:A)+IF(((COUNTIF(B:B, A:A)>0)+(COUNTIF(C:C, A:A)>0)+(COUNTIF(D:D, A:A)>0))=3, 0, 1), 0)),"")
```

---

[image]

---

You can consider using a UDF via VBA as well

Comment: My Column names are B,G,M and Q , could you help me with that please, the formula is lil complicated

Comment: Look at the picture and formula. I'm using A through D - so just swap them out for your columns in the formula accordingly .... minimal effort is expected on your part

Comment: giving empty results